# wxWidgets Loop through sizers contained by parent sizer and access their controls

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a sizer (row_wrap_sizer) that contains several rows.

Each row is itself a sizer that contains the same controls in each row (checkboxes and comboboxes). What makes each row different is the values checked or entered into the controls can be different.

On a button click, I need to be able to iterate through each child sizer contained by row_wrap_sizer, and see what values were entered into the controls. I think I've figured out how to loop through each row, but I don't know how to access the controls. This is as far as I've gotten for the event handler for clicking the button to loop through the children sizers:

```
void MyFrame::Calculate(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxString output = "Calculating...";

    // get children in the sizer
    wxSizerItemList children = row_wrap_sizer->GetChildren();

    // loop through each child (a node?)
    for (wxSizerItemList::Node *node = children.GetFirst(); node; node = node->GetNext())
    {
        output += wxT("Child...");
    }

    log_output->SetValue(output);
}
```

This loops through the children, but as I'm looping I don't know how to find the controls inside each node and check their values. For example, each child row contains a wxComboBox with the name "Combo1", and I need to find this within each row and check its value while I'm iterating.

Also, its important that I iterate through each row in the order that they appear in the parent sizer, and I'm not sure my code is doing this but I have no way to test because i can't access the controls in each sizer

This is the entire code modified from minimal wxWidgdets example, so should just plug and play:

```
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resources
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the application icon (under Windows and OS/2 it is in resources and even
// though we could still include the XPM here it would be unused)
#ifndef wxHAS_IMAGES_IN_RESOURCES
    #include "../sample.xpm"
#endif



#include <vector>


// Define a new application type, each program should derive a class from wxApp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    // override base class virtuals
    // ----------------------------

    // this one is called on application startup and is a good place for the app
    // initialization (doing it here and not in the ctor allows to have an error
    // return: if OnInit() returns false, the application terminates)
    virtual bool OnInit();
};


// Define a new frame type: this is going to be our main frame
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    // ctor(s)
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);

    // event handlers (these functions should _not_ be virtual)
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    // any class wishing to process wxWidgets events must use this macro
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

    wxPanel *main_panel;
    wxTextCtrl *log_output;
    wxBoxSizer *row_wrap_sizer;

    void Calculate(wxCommandEvent& event);

};


// IDs for the controls and the menu commands
enum
{
    // menu items
    Minimal_Quit = wxID_EXIT,

    // it is important for the id corresponding to the "About" command to have
    // this standard value as otherwise it won't be handled properly under Mac
    // (where it is special and put into the "Apple" menu)
    Minimal_About = wxID_ABOUT
};


// the event tables connect the wxWidgets events with the functions (event
// handlers) which process them. It can be also done at run-time, but for the
// simple menu events like this the static method is much simpler.
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_Quit,  MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

// Create a new application object: this macro will allow wxWidgets to create
// the application object during program execution (it's better than using a
// static object for many reasons) and also implements the accessor function
// wxGetApp() which will return the reference of the right type (i.e. MyApp and
// not wxApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)


// 'Main program' equivalent: the program execution "starts" here
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    // call the base class initialization method, currently it only parses a
    // few common command-line options but it could be do more in the future
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");

    // and show it (the frames, unlike simple controls, are not shown when
    // created initially)
    frame->Show(true);

    // success: wxApp::OnRun() will be called which will enter the main message
    // loop and the application will run. If we returned false here, the
    // application would exit immediately.
    return true;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main frame
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    // set the frame icon
    SetIcon(wxICON(sample));

    #if wxUSE_MENUS
        // create a menu bar
        wxMenu *fileMenu = new wxMenu;

        // the "About" item should be in the help menu
        wxMenu *helpMenu = new wxMenu;
        helpMenu->Append(Minimal_About, "&About\tF1", "Show about dialog");

        fileMenu->Append(Minimal_Quit, "E&xit\tAlt-X", "Quit this program");

        // now append the freshly created menu to the menu bar...
        wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
        menuBar->Append(fileMenu, "&File");
        menuBar->Append(helpMenu, "&Help");

        // ... and attach this menu bar to the frame
        SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    #endif // wxUSE_MENUS

    #if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
        // create a status bar just for fun (by default with 1 pane only)
        CreateStatusBar(2);
        SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
    #endif // wxUSE_STATUSBAR



    // mainPanel
    main_panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

    // main_panel_sizer (vertical)
    // goes onto the panel, contains 3 sizers
    wxBoxSizer *main_panel_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);


    // sizer 1: but_wrap_sizer, contains row of buttons along top
    wxBoxSizer *but_wrap_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(but_wrap_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    wxButton *go_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "GO");
    go_but->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::Calculate, this);
    but_wrap_sizer->Add(go_but, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


    // sizer 2: output_sizer, contains a txtctrl we can log output to
    wxBoxSizer *output_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(output_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    log_output = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
    output_sizer->Add(log_output, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


    // sizer 3: row_wrap_sizer, contains a bunch of rows of data,
    // each row it contains is itself a sizer and contains the same controls,
    // but controls can be set to have diff values
    row_wrap_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(row_wrap_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {

        wxBoxSizer *row_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        row_wrap_sizer->Add(row_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        std::vector<wxString> filters_in_deck;
        filters_in_deck.push_back("A");
        filters_in_deck.push_back("B");
        filters_in_deck.push_back("C");

        wxGridSizer *checkbox_sizer = new wxGridSizer(1, 3, 0, 0);
        row_sizer->Add(checkbox_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < filters_in_deck.size(); i++ )
        {
            wxCheckBox *filter_check = new wxCheckBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, "filter " + filters_in_deck[i], wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, "Checkbox");
            checkbox_sizer->Add(filter_check, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
        }

        wxComboBox *combo_box_a = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString);
        combo_box_a->SetName("Combo1");
        combo_box_a->Append("Any");
        combo_box_a->Append("All");
        row_sizer->Add(combo_box_a, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        wxComboBox *combo_box_b = new wxComboBox(this->main_panel, wxID_ANY);
        combo_box_a->SetName("Combo2");
        combo_box_b->Append("If");
        combo_box_b->Append("Or");
        row_sizer->Add(combo_box_b, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    }

    // done
    main_panel->SetSizerAndFit(main_panel_sizer);
    this->Fit();

}


void MyFrame::Calculate(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxString output = "Calculating...";

    // get children in the sizer
    wxSizerItemList children = row_wrap_sizer->GetChildren();

    // loop through each child (a node?)
    for (wxSizerItemList::Node *node = children.GetFirst(); node; node = node->GetNext())
    {
        output += wxT("Child...");

        //wxSizerItem child_sizer = node.GetData().GetSizer();

    }

    log_output->SetValue(output);
}


// event handlers
void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    // true is to force the frame to close
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format
                 (
                    "Welcome to %s!\n"
                    "\n"
                    "This is the minimal wxWidgets sample\n"
                    "running under %s.",
                    wxVERSION_STRING,
                    wxGetOsDescription()
                 ),
                 "About wxWidgets minimal sample",
                 wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION,
                 this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to assign an id to each control in the sizer and not to use wxID_ANY.

And if you want to know the type `dynamic_cast()` or `wxDynamicCast()` will help.